How is it possible to discuss philosophy if natural language and other factors lead to uncertainty?
I’ve always felt that human natural language is too ambiguous for philosophical questions. Philosophical viewpoints either (1) cannot clearly convey their meanings or (2) rely on too many assumptions. For example, “I think, therefore I am.” It’s unclear what “I” and “think” actually mean, and it’s also debatable whether I truly “think” at all.
I understand that there may be extensive explanations attempting to make this sentence more precise, but this is just one example. My impression is that it’s nearly impossible to truly define everything from scratch and clarify meaning comprehensively. There may be formal language and logic that attempt to construct an impeccable tower of reasoning, but I believe most philosophical literature does not achieve this. (I also admit that while I have a college-level understanding of logic from studying math, I haven’t formally delved into subjects like Gödel’s incompleteness theorems, etc.)
And even if such a “tower” of reasoning exists, I have another question (although I acknowledge that this question itself is based on questionable assumptions):
“Spectrum Hypothesis”: Just as the human eye can only perceive certain wavelengths of visible light, perhaps human logic and reasoning are merely products of brain structure and are fundamentally unreliable. (For instance, maybe even the concept of “yes or no” doesn’t truly exist.) This hypothesis has made it impossible for me to fully “trust” any form of logic or thought. I also realize that even this hypothesis itself might stem from the brain’s own logic and reasoning, making everything feel absurd.
These two issues have made it challenging for me to seriously discuss these topics with others or to engage with philosophical literature. Additionally, I developed a type of paranoia because people seemed either indifferent to these questions or willing to accept the ambiguities of language, discussing philosophical concepts with ease. I suspected that they were hiding their thoughts and had malicious intentions, as many arguments sounded extremely absurd, shaky, and ill-defined, yet people took them seriously and debated over them with a similar level of vagueness. (I still cannot fully let go of this doubt.)
I asked a philosophy professor about this, and he told me that my questions unsurprisingly echo those raised in history. He mentioned that historically, people sought but ultimately failed in their quest for “certainty” and “precision,” gradually abandoning it. He also noted that modern philosophers often adopt a “reflective equilibrium” approach (which, in his words, sounds like just following one’s heart), something I did not understand or accept.
I wonder whether this doubt about language and logic is “solved” or not. And if they cannot be solved, how is it possible to proceed with any "meaningful" discussion?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You seem to think that the goal of philosophy is the stark determination of Truth, in which case, given philosophy has given up on a scientific language à la Carnapp, it is a hopeless endeavour. That is not the case. If anything, philosophical discourse aims at coming closer to the truth. It is a dialectical process that is never "finished". Ultimately, sense and truth are something that is built in practice. If you do not partake, you have no say in it.
Part of that is that language is necessarily bound to our interactions with the world, ie. only that which is part of human interaction with their environment can make sense to humans (see Wittgenstein,  Plessner, and others). Therefore, discussing philosophy is possible because we share (similar) experiences that make us understand and conceptualise the world in similar ways. Insofar, your spectrum hypothesis is not necessarily wrong, but too narrow in scope: The limitations of our understanding are not due to brain structure as if it was some absolute. The brain is malleable, and so is language and understanding, given there is new experience altering it. Most of that only becomes visible over larger time frames, ie. through history.
Given that, why should we bother having philosophical discourse at all? Because there are always persons out there who have had a richer experience, or at least different ones, which allows us to ever widen our own, limited horizon. We can still learn different perspectives, different arguments, and different ways of life. The goal should not be calcified and supposedly eternal, absolute knowledge but individual and collective growth.
For some name dropping you can read this answer of mine, and for some metaphorical but IMHO highly relevant quote, see Adorno's Minima Moralia, Aphorism 153:

At the end. – The only philosophy which would still be accountable in the face of despair, would be the attempt to consider all things, as they would be portrayed from the standpoint of redemption. Cognition has no other light than that which shines from redemption out upon the world; all else exhausts itself in post-construction and remains a piece of technics. Perspectives must be produced which set the world beside itself, alienated from itself, revealing its cracks and fissures, as needy and distorted as it will one day lay there in the messianic light. To win such perspectives without caprice or violence, wholly by the feel for objects, this alone is what thinking is all about. It is the simplest of all things, because the condition irrefutably call for such cognitions, indeed because completed negativity, once it comes fully into view, shoots [zusammenschiesst] into the mirror-writing of its opposite. But it is also that which is totally impossible, because it presupposes a standpoint at a remove, were it even the tiniest bit, from the bane [Bannkreis] of the existent; meanwhile every possible cognition must not only be wrested from that which is, in order to be binding, but for that very reason is stricken with the same distortedness and neediness which it intends to escape. The more passionately thought seals itself off from its conditional being for the sake of what is unconditional, the more unconsciously, and thereby catastrophically, it falls into the world. It must comprehend even its own impossibility for the sake of possibility. In relation to the demand thereby imposed on it, the question concerning the reality or non-reality of redemption is however almost inconsequential.

The message is that thought necessarily misses what it aspires to if it tries to capture truth in a single frame. It needs to inquire and probe, take different forms and takes on the matter, to gradually get a better grip. This Hegelian insight seems to better fit the human condition considering 20th century philosophy.

Your first paragraph is merely your opinion about what the goal of philosophy is. Many, for example, do see it as a means to seek truth, and yes, objective truth at that.

I don't expect philosophy to resolve truth. I expect it to help us understand what would be considered proof or disproof of truth.

@Syed Philosophy itself has followed that goal to the point where the inner contradictions with the conditio humana were laid bare. This was in the early 20th century. Therefore, we need to adjust our aspirations accordingly.

"Because there are always persons out there who have had a richer experience, or at least different ones, which allows us to ever widen our own, limited horizon." That seems very much not the case on this site.

Being exposed to other opinions, even demonstrably false ones, does constitute a richer experience. So does engaging in discussion over why ideas are considered correct or mistaken. Ditto the processes leading to those conclusions. An open mind need not accept every bit of dust dumped into it, it need only look seriously at that dust before discarding it as unhelpful. And that, I think, is very much the case on this site.


[H]uman logic and reasoning are merely products of brain structure and are fundamentally unreliable. (For instance, maybe even the concept of “yes or no” doesn’t truly exist.) This hypothesis has made it impossible for me to fully “trust” any form of logic or thought.

If you see it as a fact that humans in their behavior and in their argumentations are unreasonable, irrational, illogical, and/or generally unreliable, then it's only to be expected, and advisable, to not trust other people's arguments and not trust even your own arguments or thoughts. This kind of distrust is a cornerstone of science.
In the recent history of mathematics and logic this kind of distrust played a role in the foundational crisis of mathematics (e.g. Frege's Begriffschrift, Brouwer's intuitionism, Hilbert's list of foundational problems). How can we be really rigorous in our proofs? What is needed for that? What is acceptable as a proof? What is a proof?
In the old Chinese text of Zhuangzi he complains of the endless disputes between the two dominant rival traditions of his day (3d century BC), the Mohists and Ruists (Confucianists), who

... assert what the others deny and deny what the others assert.

He comments:

If you really want to assert what they (both) deny and deny what they assert, the best thing is to use clarity [literally: use light].

This seems singularly unclear, but the only general way to summarize the progress in mathematical logic and in the philosophy of mathematics during the last century is, I think, by saying that we did get more clarity about various issues and various concepts (proof, completeness of a theory, consistency, truth, defineability, algorithm, finite, infinite...).
The general approach to become more reliable, more trustworthy, ensure a wider and deeper consensus, and perhaps also a deeper subjective certainty, has been to externalize the thinking. In logic this has been the effort -- starting with Frege's Begriffsschrift inspired by Leibniz dream of a universal clear language -- to standardize and formalize logic. This by itself already almost forces you to be more precise (to select exactly those components that you believe are relevant). The motivation to formalize is exactly that natural language is often too ambiguous, fluid, vague, unclear. So, again, to provide more clarity - make your argument or proof more conspicuous. Even before the concept of "mechanical procedure" was made completely clear (by Turing and Gödel in the 1930's), this provided a clearer external standard that could be used both to express logical arguments (or the structural, logical form of an argument) and to certify them as valid.
This same motivation is also expressed in Wittgenstein's notion of a "clear overview" (übersichtliche Darstellung):

A main source of our failure to understand is that we do not command a clear view of the use of our words. —- Our grammar is lacking in this sort of perspicuity. A perspicuous representation produces just that understanding which consists in 'seeing connexions'. (Philosophical Investigations, 122)

Exactly how Wittgenstein hoped to get this for philosophical questions is pretty unclear though. But I believe the motivation is the same as the one that led logicians to try to externalize the thoughts into formalisms.
In short, my answer is: To gain trust or reliability, we need external standards that we can refer to and use. As long as -- or in sofar as -- we do not have those, some distrust in the truth, soundness or validity of our beliefs and arguments is always justified. In mathematical logic we have a kind of standard -- unfortunately, even though this standard is important, its practical use outside of mathematics is rather limited. (Mainly because lack of logical validity does not seem to be the main source of error, confusion or unreliablity in general arguments.)
But even in mathematical logic, it's good to keep any lingering unease, doubts or questions alive. To give an example - very recently a well-known, well-respected mathematician proposed that the standard interpretation of Gödel's second incompleteness result, an interpretation that has been commonly accepted for almost a century, is wrong; that the formal expression used by Gödel to express that the theory of arithmetic is "consistent" is too strong and that a more natural formalization of "consistency" is possible and enables us to prove in the theory of arithmetic that the theory is consistent. (See: The Provability of Consistency and Serial properties, selector proofs and the provability of consistency(2024) by Sergei Artemov.)
You may have read Wittgenstein's battle cry:

Philosophy is a battle against the bewitchment of our intelligence by means of language. (Philosophical Investigations, 109)

I would say: The difficulty in philosophy is self-evident intuitions. We have certain intuitions, that may appear self-evident to us, but not to others, yet we cannot shake them and cannot pinpoint what makes us right and the others wrong. This can become a real, big problem in a historical social perspective on morality and meta-morality. (How was it possible at all that people in the early 19th century US tried to justify slavery or tried to find a compromis for allowing slave states? -- Those people must have been living a different moral universe than mine. But of course, there are also more recent issues...)

Philosophy, from its root words, simply means, "the love of wisdom." I does not mean having all of the answers, but simply the search for those answers and an appreciation for the questions. We can discuss these questions and potential answers without having conclusive answers.
Philosophy is not science
Let me compare and contrast science. Science is a method, one which is aimed at finding answers also, from a different direction. We don't know everything yet that science might discover, but we can still have meaningful scientific discussions. In that way, the two are similar. They differ, however, in that for science, it deals strictly in absolutes, meaning that it accommodates more consensus, but it is more restricted in the topics it can address. There can be multiple competing and even conflicting Philosophical schools of thought which can all be valid.
Discussion simply requires a consensus or a mutual frame of reference. This allows us to work meaningfully on specific issues without having to fully prove out the core assumptions. Consider the Trolley Problems. We can all meaningfully discuss them to find value in moral considerations without knowing whether trolleys or people even exist, or whether or not there is even an objective morality or ethical consensus. They allow us to see what things may or may not be problematic in certain situations, and then leaves it to some other contemplation to prove or disprove the required assumptions. In this way, we can each tackle isolated parts of the problem.
If you can break your problems down into small, isolated, parts, then people will be more willing to engage. However, admittedly, there is going to be some bike-shedding as people tend to focus on certain areas that interest them.
Where is the start?
This brings us to the heart of your question, which seems to be asking, if we were to begin at the start, without using any unnecessary assumptions or consensus or shorthands for argument sake, what could we know, and could we discuss it with others? The first thing you should expect, as you have found, is that this would drastically reduce the number of people interested in engaging in the conversation. The more fundamental the question, the more real life beliefs will have to be subjected to scrutiny, and so the more work they would need to invest in deconstruction. Many people who have attempted that exploration have found that they did not like the way the answers were starting to look, and others simply couldn't find a workable solution.
The beginning is still assumption
Some people have attempted this. For instance, you mention Descartes. He gave us the Cogito. The "I" doesn't necessarily mean to imply anything about what "I" am. "I" could simply be an instantaneous disembodied thought. And the "think" isn't necessarily some specific form of thought or reason. Descartes was simply interested there in the fact that the moment that he had a thought that he didn't exist, the fact that he had that thought would contradict itself. So, if we want to know what is true undeniably, the Cogito is about it. Even Descartes found that he couldn't proceed from the Cogito without making some assumptions. For him, he assumed God. From there, he assumed a relation ship between that God and the "I" such that naive observations would be valid, which informed his thoughts on the "I", the "think", and other beliefs. Others struggled with similar problems, such as Hume with the Problem of Induction and the Uniformity of nature, and found that he couldn't proceed without some kind of assumptions as well since he wanted to observe a world through a scientific lens, and that requires many assumptions before you can even begin.
This makes sense because intuitively (and according to many theories of "knowledge", like JTB, what we "know" is related to what we can justify, so we need some starting place which itself doesn't beg further justification. Since we don't have "truth" sensor capability, and since undeniable truth leads to no further justification, the only truth that seems possible is relative truth, with the hope that such relative truth is also actual truth. The question, then, is how do we find the sufficient starting place, the assumptions which are best warranted? This is not an easy question, and is in fact a valid part of philosophy, though won't be something you can discuss with the average person on the streets.
My solution
What follows is merely an example of how I go about finding this starting place, in the hopes that it might be useful to you or others, and example of how we can have such a discussion. Also, it is only a very generalized overview.
After much contemplation, it seems to me that there are two fundamental and necessary assumptions. These are necessary because they are implied by the current endeavor itself.
Reason
The first is "reason". It is entirely possible, as you have noticed, that logic and reason might not exist at all and even possible that my very impression that I can reason is an illusion, and so, unlike the Cotigo, I cannot say that it is a fact that I can reason. However, if I am unable to reason in any productive manner at all, then I could never reliably reach the conclusion that I cannot. I could feel like I can't reason, but feelings are mutable and maybe the next moment I'll feel like I can. The point here is that I can't prove that I can reason, but I can reasonably assume that I can, or at least, I categorically cannot be convinced reasonably that I can't reason.
This opens up a large division between potential beliefs and "knowledge". There's those which can validate my ability to reason and those which cannot. Those in the latter group might be true, but are in contradiction with my ability to proceed with contemplating them in a rational way. So, if they were true, than I would have to fall back to trusting my emotion, intuition, habit, or some other, more mutable method of viewing the world, but for me, all of those suggest that I should use reason, so I'd end up back assuming reason.
However, if I look at the remaining group of beliefs and potential knowledge which do affirm my ability to reason, that provides me with an infinite set of possible worlds, many of which are mutually exclusive. This is the actual end of reason by itself. I could say that the world around me as observed through my empirical senses is reasonable. I could also say that the world of Descartes' Demon is also reasonable, as well as Boltzmann Brains, and an infinite set of other possible worlds. We haven't said what is true and we haven't narrowed anything down into an exclusive truth or category, but that isn't the job of reason alone.
Impetus
That solution, intuitively, does not seem satisfying. When we ask the questions of philosophy, we don't merely want to know what could be possible. We want something more. It seems to me that the other necessary assumption implied by our quest is "impetus". That is, we don't only want to know what could be believed, but what we should believe, or what is "best", with "best" being subtly relative to some desired end that it should accomplish. We think about questions like "What method should I use to arrive at truth?"
Unlike undeniable truth or reason alone, such a method quickly blossoms out into many derived beliefs. For instance, I can safely believe that time exists in some manner because if all reality were static, then I would lack any impetus to believe anything at all, as I would simply believe only what I believe since I couldn't change my belief without time. This is just one of many beliefs, and together, they seem to me to form a scaffolding from which we can begin to piece together a framework for knowledge, and one which I believe leads to exclusivity as well.
Practically reasonable beliefs
So, to the question of what is true, I have hope that I know, but cannot convey a tool to you which can confirm it. To the question of what is undeniably true, I can say that is only the Cogito. To the question of what is reasonably true, I can say that there is an infinite set of mutually exclusive possible things. Instead, I focus on what I should reasonably believe to be true.
For me, this comes in the form of attempting to find a core set of assumptions from which all other beliefs can be weighed. The fewer assumptions, the less likely to have a false assumption, but we do need to find a set which can affirm our two criteria. I would call this set a "world view", "core beliefs", or perhaps "faith."
Once we have the first order of beliefs in place, we also must acknowledge that if we have the ability to reason and we should use it, then we should only accept our belief about our ability to reason if it is itself reasonable, which means that just because the question implies reason and impetus, that doesn't mean we get a free pass. Now we must analyze any potential world against whether or not it can provide us with sufficient justification for impetus and reason, and how well it can do so. It is my suspicion that such a method might lead us to a single, exclusive truth.
The "problem"
As you might have noticed, there is something unpleasant here for many people. When we introduce impetus with reason, we go down a road which would quickly start implying things like objective morality, a rational direct causal link existing between things believed and the beliefs we hold, and, considering the Is-ought problem, implies the immaterial. In other words, such a method strongly favors Theistic models of truth. Consider Plantinga's Evolutionary Argument Against Naturalism (EAAN) and the Transcendental Argument for God (TAG). Even so, I personally cannot seem to find any other method which allows for starting with only the assumptions implied in the inquiry.

You say:

I wonder whether this doubt about language and logic is “solved” or not. And if they cannot be solved, how is it possible to proceed with any "meaningful" discussion?

The problem of skepticism goes back to the Pre-Socratics. The longing for certainty exerts a powerful pull on the human psychology. But today, many philosophers, particularly those who study epistemology advocate a position called fallibilism (IEP):

Fallibilism is the epistemological thesis that no belief (theory, view, thesis, and so on) can ever be rationally supported or justified in a conclusive way. Always, there remains a possible doubt as to the truth of the belief. Fallibilism applies that assessment even to science’s best-entrenched claims and to people’s best-loved commonsense views.

In fact, understanding and using language itself is subject to probabilistic inference. Relevance theory for instance advocates that all communications, be they explicatures or implicatures are best guesses, and not certain. From the article:

On hearing an utterance, the addressee first concludes that the presumption of optimal relevance is met. He then decodes it, which however yields only very incomplete information. Usually, most of the information conveyed by the utterance has to be inferred. The inference process is based on the decoded meaning, the addressee's knowledge and beliefs, and the context, and is guided by the communicative principle of relevance.

Thus, there are no certainties, and we get on in the world doing what is most likely to obtain or achieve our goals. From the battlefield to the bookshelf, we can only seek to minimize uncertainty, and never really overcome it. Philosophy, in this regard, is no different from any other intellectual pursuit in life.
